# LASSO kernel for nonparametric models

Tags: performance, r

I am a novice in nonparametric modeling and have recently begun exploring the world of varying coefficient models. Essentially, these models involve a non-linear least squares problem that relies on kernel weights. My current challenge is the slow performance of my R code, which is the only programming language I am familiar with.

Here is my code for the kernel and the unpenalized varying coefficient models:

```
############################################################################
############################################################################
###                                                                      ###
###                        KERNEL WEIGHT FUNCTION                        ###
###                                                                      ###
############################################################################
############################################################################

M.kernel <- function(index.var, method){
  stopifnot(!missing(index.var) | !missing(method))
  
  n = length(c(index.var))
  U = outer(index.var, index.var, "-")
  W = matrix(NA, n, n)
  
  # Epanechnikov
  if (method == "epanechnikov") {
    
    h = 2.345 * sd(index.var) * n**(-1/5)
    for (i in 1:n) {
      
      W[,i] <- 0.75 / h * (1 - (U[,i] / h)**2) * (abs(U[,i] / h) <= 1)
      W[i,i] <- 0
      W[,i] <- W[,i] / sum(c(W[,i]))
    }
  # Gauss  
  } else if (method == "Gauss") {
    
    h = 1.06 * sd(index.var) * n**(-1/5)
    for (i in 1:n) {
      
      W[,i] <- 1 / sqrt(2 * pi) * exp(-0.50 * (U[,i] / h)**2)
      W[i,i] <- 0
      W[,i] <- W[,i] / sum(c(W[,i]))
    }
    
  } 
  
  W
}


###########################################################################
###########################################################################
###                                                                     ###
###                UNPENALIZED VARYING COEFFICIENT MODEL                ###
###                                                                     ###
###########################################################################
###########################################################################

M.vcm <- function(y, X, index.var, kernel.type){
  stopifnot(!missing(y) | !missing(X) | !missing(index.var) | !missing(kernel.type))
  
  n = nrow(X)
  p = ncol(X)
  U = outer(index.var, index.var, "-")
  W = M.kernel(index.var, kernel.type)
  
  ab = matrix(NA, n, 2 * p)
  IH = 1e-4 * diag(2 * p)
  
  for (i in 1:n) {
    x_xu = cbind(X, U[,i]*X)
    if (kernel.type == "epanechnikov") {
      ab[i,] = solve(crossprod(x_xu*W[,i], x_xu)) %*% crossprod(x_xu*W[,i], y)
    } else {
      ab[i,] = solve(crossprod(x_xu*W[,i], x_xu) + IH) %*% crossprod(x_xu*W[,i], y) # aviod singularity with Epanechnikov kernel
    }
  }
  ab
}
```

I am particularly interested in the penalized VCM, as presented in the work of [Wang and Xia (2015)](https://www.readcube.com/articles/10.2139%2Fssrn.1305588) work. I am not positive that my steps are accurate because when I run a small simulation I get unexpected results. My code for the Shrinkage Estimation of Varying Coefficient Models is

```
###########################################################################
###########################################################################
###                                                                     ###
###                                KLASSO                               ###
###                              DEVELOPED                              ###
###                                                                     ###
###########################################################################
###########################################################################

KLASSO <- function(y, X, index.var, kernel.type,
                   penalty.lambda = 10**seq(-1,1, length = 20),
                   max.itr = 100, eps = 1e-5){
 stopifnot(!missing(y) | !missing(X) | !missing(index.var) | !missing(kernel.type))
  
  n  = nrow(X)
  p  = ncol(X)
  n0 = length(penalty.lambda)
  W  = M.kernel(index.var, kernel.type)
  
  if (kernel.type == "epanechnikove") {
    h = 2.345 * sd(index.var) * n**(-1/5)
  } else {
    h = 1.06 * sd(index.var) * n**(-1/5)
  }
  
  
  # STEP ONE: Fit unpenalized VCM
  AB_0 = M.vcm(y, X, index.var, kernel.type)
  A_0 = AB_0[,1:p]
  
  # STEP TWO: Prepare \lambda
  lambda = matrix(NA,p, n0)
  for(i in 1:n0) {
    lambda[,i] = penalty.lambda[i] / sqrt(colSums(A_0**2)) * sqrt(n)
  }
  
  # STEP THREE: Iteration
  
  A = array(NA, dim = c(n,p,n0))
  for (i in 1:n0) {
    A_old = A_0
    A_new = matrix(NA,n,p)
    
    for (j in 1:max.itr) {
      D     = diag(lambda[,i] / sqrt(colSums(A_old**2)))
      D     = ifelse(D == Inf, 1e5, D)
      
      for (k in 1:n) {
        A_new[k,] = solve(crossprod(X*W[,k],X) + D) %*% crossprod(X*W[,k],y)
        A_new[k,] = ifelse(abs(A_new[k,]) <= 1e-4, 0, A_new[k,])
      }
      
      if (max(abs(sqrt(colSums(A_new**2)) - sqrt(colSums(A_old**2)))) < eps) {
        cat(" Converged in ", j, "\n")
        break
      }
      
      if (j == max.itr) {
        cat(" Did not converge \n")
        break
      }
      A_old = A_new
    }
    
    A[,,i] = A_new
    
  }
  
  # STEP FOUR: Pick the best BIC and its corresponding Coefficient Matrix
  bic = c()
  Y = matrix(y, n, n)
  for (i in 1:n0) {
    bic[i] = log(n**(-2) * sum((Y - tcrossprod(X, A[,,i]))**2 * W)) + 
             sum(colSums(A[,,i]**2) != 0) * log(n * h) / (n * h)
  }
  
  return(list(BIC = bic,
              best_bic = bic[which.min(bic)],
              best_A = A[,,which.min(bic)]))
}
```

I am convinced that there is potential for improving the efficiency of this code and achieving better execution.

Comment: Does "_when I run a small simulation I get unexpected results_" mean that your code isn't yet **working as intended**?  If you believe your implementation is incorrect, then it's not yet ready for review (and certainly not ready for optimisation - getting the wrong results faster isn't considered particularly helpful!)

Comment: When I read the paper's simulation, it says that the authors conducted 1000 samples for three different models. for my code, it takes roughly 2 min to finish the KLASSO algorithm. In short, It is very slow code.